# Image Source from C# XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I need to set Image Source from C#.  I tried `X:Name="headimg"` but I could not find headimg in C#.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Body">
<Image x:Name="headimg" Source="img/logo.png" Height="120" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void SetImage()
{
    BitmapImage imge = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Images/ImageName.png", UriKind.Relative));
    headimg.Source=image.Source;
}
```